# Java - Very large queue (too big for Heap)

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, heap-memory, large-data

I am working on an algorithm that uses a very large queue.
For all but toy problems, it's too big to fit in the heap.
As a queue, that's fine: performance depends only on the first N entries (dequeuing) and the last N entries (enqueueing), so it would be fine to keep all the middle on disk.

Are there libraries or middleware that can do this?
If not, how can I implement it?

I could use an RDBMS, but this is an algorithm where I need very fast access to enqueue and dequeue, so I don't want to use a traditional RDBMS.

Comment: Do you know, can you state the size of the heap and the queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many databases can profitably employ as much memory as you can give them - profile your code before you complain that they are too slow. Also consider using non-RDBMS stores such as REDIS.

If you decide to implement it yourself, you can build your own disk-backed Dequeue by implementing a [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) on top of a (huge) [mmaped file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html). You would start with a single `MappedByteBuffer` pointing to the read-write region; as these regions drift further apart, you would begin to keep two non-overlapping `MappedByteBuffer`s pointing to the write-end and the read-end.